# Windows Phone 8.1 App crashes on ShowShareUI()

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to add share functionality to my Windows Phone App. The code behaves in an unpredictable way. Sometimes it works, but mostly it doesn't and I haven't been able to get any details about what's causing the crash. Could someone please go through the code below and let me know if I've missed something? Thanks!

```
public ArticlePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //..
    RegisterForShare();
}

private void RegisterForShare()
{
    DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager,
        DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareLinkHandler);
}

private void ShareLinkHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    DataRequestDeferral defferal = request.GetDeferral();

    request.Data.Properties.Title = this.article.Title;
    request.Data.Properties.Description = this.article.Summary;
    request.Data.SetWebLink(new Uri(this.article.UrlDomain));

    defferal.Complete();
}

private void ShareCommand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

**UPDATE**

The code always works while I'm debugging from visual studio but pretty much never otherwise. I made a release build thinking there might be some code in the debug build which is causing the problem but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: try setting the RegisterForShare(); in the OnNavigatedTo instead of the constructor.

Comment: Tried that. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: put all the functions with try catch and display any error to pinpoint the error because what is provided is insufficient to help you more.

Comment: @W.K.S Try my answer now and tell me if it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I had the same problem. ShowShareUi actually suspends your app. If you try suspending your app you would get the error. It is actually the serialization problem.

If you want to look into the error, then while debugging, press the lifecycle events and suspend, you will crash in debug mode now.

[image: suspend in debug mode]

If you are navigating between pages with a custom class you would get error. ***My suggestion is that you would convert to *jsonstring* and send and get it back.***

Comment: This finally helped me debug the issue. The problem was that I was sending an obejct as a NavigationParameter. I fixed it by converting the object to a string like you recommended :D

Comment: @W.K.S I'm also facing similar issue, could you update your answer about object to string?

Comment: @mehul9595 Override tostring method in your custom object or try using library from http://www.newtonsoft.com/json. newtonsoft is a very popular library.

Comment: @Mani: to understand more correctly from above example, do you mean instead of doing this.article.Title (or any other field), pass in a string representation instead?

Comment: @mehul9595 Use newtonsoft library and it will give a string representation of that object. use that string as parameter to send between pages. In the receiving page convert that string back to object using library.

Answer (score 4):

I also had that problem recently. The share UI crashes when one of the important parameters is not set. In your case I'd suspect that

```
this.article.UrlDomain
```

is null or not a valid Uri pattern. You should build an if-clause around it and make sure that you're dealing with a real Uri. To test your code you should insert hardcoded constants and run it again. If it doesn't crash, check your `Title`, `Summary` and `UrlDomain` one by one.

**Other places to investigate:**

Try adding your handler in the OnNavigatedTo method and remove it when you're leaving the page

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += SharePage_DataRequested;
}

protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested -= SharePage_DataRequested;
}
```

I also searched my code and looked at official samples again and did not find any defferals. Just to be sure - if I were you I'd strip all unnessecary lines in my code and get it as closest as possible to the official examples and then extend it back to where it was from there which is why I would comment out these two lines as well:

```
void SharePage_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    //DataRequestDeferral defferal = request.GetDeferral();

    request.Data.Properties.Title = this.article.Title;
    request.Data.Properties.Description = this.article.Summary;
    request.Data.SetWebLink(new Uri(this.article.UrlDomain));
    //defferal.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the URLs and they're all fine.

Comment: I added a few thoughts. If I have some time later I'll go and try out your code.

Comment: I tried out all of your comments but none of them made a difference. It still crashes

Comment: @Fred Did you try to share hardcoded values? In other words, build a minimal example of the problem you're experiencing and work up from there.

Comment: @MarkusBruckner: You must be mistaken. This is not my question ;) And I already suggested that.

Comment: @Fred Yes, I meant to comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar problem (crash on ShowShareUI).
After very long investigations I've found, that this appears because unhandled exception in SaveFrameNavigationState (SuspensionManager class from template project).
In my case it was because SessionStateForFrame method failed on parsing class that couldn't be serialized.
Check out what you're saving in page state on SaveState of the page.
It happens not only on ShowShareUI but in suspend mode generally.